# Add click event on file upload in ASP

Tags: jquery, asp.net, file-upload

I have an application that will preview image every time I browse using file upload in asp.

This is my code:

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:Panel ID="stage" runat="server" cssClass="containment-wrapper" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
         <asp:Image ID="imgBrowse" runat="server" Height="375px" Width="640px" ImageUrl="Image/ClickHere.png" style="cursor:pointer"/>
         <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload_IE" runat="server" style="display:none;" />
         <asp:Button ID="btn_UploadHandler" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btn_UploadHandler_Click" style="display:none;"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#stage").click(function () {
    if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
        $('#FileUpload_IE')[0].click();       
    }
});


$("#FileUpload_IE").on("change", function () {
        $("#btn_UploadHandler").click();
});
```

This code has error in `$("#btn_UploadHandler").click();` when I run in IE8. The error is in the jquery-1.10.2.js.

```
Exception was thrown at line 5039, column 7 in http://localhost:25386/Script/jquery-1.10.2.js:

 // Prevent re-triggering of the same event, since we already bubbled it above
jQuery.event.triggered = type;
   try {

      elem[ type ]();

   } catch ( e ) {
           // IE<9 dies on focus/blur to hidden element (#1486,#12518)
          // only reproducible on winXP IE8 native, not IE9 in IE8 mode
   }
jQuery.event.triggered = undefined;
```

it stops in `elem[ type ]();`.

Any alternative how to accomplish this?

Comment: May it's helpful to use native functionality like `$("#btn_UploadHandler")[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));` More info at <https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events>

Comment: Not compatible with IE.